# Need to prevent PHP regex segfault

Tags: php, regex, stack-overflow, pcre

Why does the following segfault, and how can I prevent it?

```
<?php

$str = ' <fieldset> <label for="go-to">Go to: </label>  ' 
       . str_repeat(' ', 10000) 
       . '<input type="submit" value="Go" /> </fieldset> </form>';

preg_match_all("@
</?(?![bisa]\b)(?!em\b)[^>]*> # starting tag, must not be one of several inline tags
(?:[^<]|</?(?:(?:[bisau]|em|strong|sup)\b)[^>]*>)* #allow text and some inline tags
[\?\!\.]+
@ix", $str, $matches);

?>
```

I believe it's causing a .... wait for it .... stack overflow.

EDIT:

The above is a simplified version the pattern that demonstrates the problem. A more complete version:

```
@
</?(?![bisa]\b)(?!em\b)[^>]*> # starting tag, must not be one of several inline tags
(?:[^<]|</?(?:(?:[bisau]|em|strong|sup)\b)[^>]*>)* # continue, allow text content and some inline tags

# normal sentence ending
[\?\!\.]+ # valid ending characters -- note elipses allowed
(?<!\b[ap]m\.)(?<!\b[ap]\.m\.)(?<!digg this\!)(?<!Stumble This\!) # disallow some  false positives that we don't care about
\s*
(?:&apos;|&\#0*34;|'|&lsquo;)?\s* # closing single quotes, in the unusual case like "he said: 'go away'".
(?:"|&quot;|&\#0*34;|&\#x0*22;|&rdquo;|&\#0*8221;|&\#x0*201D;|''|``|\xe2\x80\x9d|&\#0*148;|&\#x0*94;|\x94|\))?\s* # followed by any kind of close-quote char
(?=\<) # should be followed by a tag.
@ix
```

The purpose is to find html blocks that appear to end at what looks like a valid English sentence ending. I have found that this method is very good at telling the difference between 'content' text (like an article body) and 'layout' text (i.e., like navigational elements). Sometimes if there's a vast amount of white space in between tags it blows up, however.

Comment: Intresting - I can reproduce the crash too. I'd suggest you deconstruct the regex, taking elements out until it stops crashing. Then see if you can take element which triggers the crash and create the simplest possible example which segfaults, and log it at bugs.php.net

Comment: I don't think it's a bug with the regex engine.  I just think you're making it build up a huge stack to handle backtracking.  Perhaps if you could explain what you're trying to capture we could suggest an alternative regex with less backtracking.

Comment: As you see, regular expressions is not a all-purpose tool. Better use a simple parser to read the structure of your markup and see what tags/elements you’ve got.

Comment: *''And some people, when confronted with regular expressions, think "I know, I'll use a catchy quote that I remember". Now they have added nothing to the discussion.''* `-- Tomalak`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would try is making all the quantifiers possessive and all the groups atomic:

```
"@</?+(?![bisa]\b)(?!em\b)[^>]*+>
(?>[^<]++|</?+(?>(?>[bisau]|em|strong|sup)\b)[^>]*+>)*+
[?!.]+
@ix"
```

I think Jeremy's right: it's not backtracking *per se* that's killing you, it's all the state info the regex engine has to save to make backtracking possible.  The regex seems to be constructed in such a way that if it ever has to backtrack, it's going to fail anyway.  So use possessive quantifiers and atomic groups and don't bother saving all that useless info.

EDIT: to allow for the sentence-ending punctuation, you could add another alternative to the second line:

```
(?>[^<?!.]++|(?![^?!.\s<]++<)[?!.]++|</?+(?>(?>[bisau]|em|strong|sup)\b)[^>]*+>)*+
```

The addition matches one or more of said characters, unless they're the last non-whitespace characters in the element.

Comment: I didn't test it, but I think you've hit the nail on the head here (although it's usually safe to agree with you on matters of regex...).

Comment: I believe PHP's regex (which is some version of PCRE) only supports atomic groupings, not possessive quantifiers. I don't believe the pattern you suggest would work because the [^<]++ would clobber the [?!.]+ at the end and not allow backtracking.

Comment: Also, sadly I don't think PHP's regex allows variable length lookbehinds, otherwise I could just do `(?>(?:[^<]|.....)*)(?<=[?!.]+...)`

Comment: PHP *does* support possessive quantifiers.

Comment: You have a point about the `[^<]++` clobbering up everything before `[?!.]+`. Although that might not be an issue if the input is always properly formed: ie. there's always an `>` before `[?!.]+`.

Comment: I'm not in a position to test this right now, but you can experiment with leaving some of the quantifiers greedy and such.  There's a lot of overlap in the effects of the atomic groups and possessive quantifiers.  But why do you need the `[?!.]+` anyway?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure that even newer versions of PHP are bundled with PCRE 7.0 which has known segment fault issues.  I don't think that there are any intentions on correcting the issue as it is technically a PCRE issue, not an issue with PHP.

If you tell us what you are attempting to accomplish your best bet would be to try to write an alternate expression.

The bug in question is: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40909

Answer (score 0):

Does this still do what you want?

```
</?(?![bisa]\b)(?!em\b)[^>]*> # starting tag, must not be one of several inline tags
(?:(?>[^<\?\!\.]*)|</?(?:(?:[bisau]|em|strong|sup)\b)[^>]*>)* #allow text and some inline tags
[\?\!\.]+
```

Comment: Close, but not quite: this will disallow any [?!.] before the [\?\!\.]+ at the end, but I want to allow them

Comment: Would you mind providing a test case where this version matches differently from yours?

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression causes massive amounts of backtracking. With 10000 characters in the middle, it would get pretty messy and slow. Still, I would not expect it to crash...!

Comment: Why wouldn't it crash?  How can backtracking be handled other than with a stack?  What happens when the stack burns through all available memory?

Comment: i think pcre's stack handling is a fixed size and relatively small actually IIRC.

Comment: I still would not expect it to crash. fail when it runs out of space, yes, but crash the program? no.

Comment: Recursion is handled by stack and that's why it overflows. Stack overflow IS out of space (handled by operating system, however with possible security flaws).

Comment: if you do something similar in python, it won't segfault. it will hang, mind you, but it won't segfault. I think pcre attempts its own stack management or something like that