# simplify a regex to reduce recursion

Tags: regex

I currently have a regex like this:

```
/^From: ((?!\n\n).)*\nSubject:.+/msu
```

with the point of matching a block that looks like this:

```
From: John Smith
Cc: Jane Smith
Subject: cat videos
```

(ie- where they're in a contiguous block) but not if there is a blank line breaking up the block, like this:

```
From: John Smith

Subject: cat videos
```

but I've been finding that my PHP script that uses this is sometimes segfaulting.  I was able to mitigate the segfaults by setting pcre.recursion_limit to a lower number (I used 8000), but it occurs to me that what I'm trying to do should be doable without a great deal of recursion.  Am I using a horribly inefficient method of catching the `\n\n` ?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722453/need-to-prevent-php-regex-segfault

Comment: Yeah, that expression can do ton of backtracking, the bigger the input, naturally, the more backtracking. Have you tried splitting the string? Maybe splitting to `[^\n]\nSubject` or something similar.

Comment: Your regex is clearly not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use simply "not a newline":

```
/^From:[^\n]*\nSubject:.+/msu
```

Comment: In the end I didn't change my regex, as the recursion_limit is preventing any more crashes.  But if it hadn't, I probably would have used something like similar to this simplification (though this appears to only match where From and Subject are on consecutive lines).  Ultimately, I probably would have used /^From:.*\nSubject:.+/msu --which could match some things I wouldn't want, but pretty rarely. (the other answers tried to assume I was parsing actual headers, which I'm not)

Answer (score 2):

This is just a terrible use for a single regex.  In addition to the performance problems you're having,  it's going to fail at straightforward problems like messages with the "Subject:" line appearing before "From:".  If you want to parse a RFC822 email header, then you really should be parsing it.

Find the empty line terminator of the header.  Join lines beginning with whitespace to the previous line (i.e. replace newline-followed-by-whitespace with a space).  Split each line at the first colon and snip leading and trailing whitespace from each side.

Or find an appropriate library to do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use regex to parse mail message reliably. Better use a [**PHP Mime Mail Parser**](https://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/) for this task. Using `Mime Mail Parser code` will be as simple as:

```
require_once('MimeMailParser.class.php');

$path = 'path/to/mail.txt';

$Parser = new MimeMailParser();
$Parser->setPath($path);

$to       = $Parser->getHeader('to');
$from     = $Parser->getHeader('from');
$subject  = $Parser->getHeader('subject');
$textBody = $Parser->getMessageBody('text');
$htmlBody = $Parser->getMessageBody('html');
```